# importing models into functions.py works one way but not the better way

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have an django app called my_app. I created a `functions.py` in it in the same location as `models.py`.

When I do `from .models import my_model` I get error that it cannot import `my_model`. This happens even when i use `my_app.models`

But when I do `from . import models` it works and I am able to do `models.my_model`.

I don't want to import all models. I want to import only `my_model` from the `models.py`.

Can anyone please help getting that better(?) way to work?

Thank you

**EDIT**

project structure

```
my_project
   |
   |__ app_one
   | 
   |__ my_app
         |
         |__ models.py
         |
         |__ functions.py
```

**EDIT 2:**

import line at the top of `functions.py`

`from my_app.models import my_model`

Comment: Not without seeing your actual code, and the app layout.

Comment: @DanielRoseman added the structure. Anything you need to know please let me. Thank you

Comment: Do you have __init__.py file inside my_app folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a circular import `models` -> ... -> `functions` -> `models`.

`from .models import my_models` doesn't work because `my_models` is not defined yet.

`from . import models` works because it imports the "empty" module. `my_models` is then defined later.

You can try to re-order your imports to avoid that circular import. Or you just use `from . import models`, it does not really make a big difference.

Comment: Oh yeah. Circular import. Thank you